# How to interpret documentation for optional JavaScript parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery

From the [documentation for `addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) I see the following pattern:

```
target.addEventListener(type, listener[, useCapture]);
```

Now I understand that `useCapture` is an optional parameter. Why does the `[` then start before the *comma* (`,`) and not immediately after the *comma* that follows the `listener` parameter? What does the enclosing pair of `[]` actually suggest apart from the fact that `useCapture` is optional? I have also seen similar documentation patterns in jQuery documentation, e.g. the [`on ()` method documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

```
.on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler(eventObject) )
```

Comment: The comma is inside the brackets because the comma belongs with the argument that follows, otherwise if you left the third argument out you'd get `target.addEventListener(type, listener,)`. That's pretty standard documentation style for optional arguments (used for quite a few languages and libraries) - the square brackets belong _only_ in the documentation, you don't add them when you actually use the function in your real code. Don't get too hung up on it...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Square brackets mean the thing inside them is optional – either you have it or you don't. It is a concise way of listing the valid invocation forms.

#### The Basic Example

*target.addEventListener(type, listener[, useCapture]);*

There are two valid forms:

```
target.addEventListener(type, listener            ); // without
target.addEventListener(type, listener, useCapture); // with
```

If the comma was outside the square brackets the two forms would be

```
target.addEventListener(type, listener,           ); // without (syntax error)
target.addEventListener(type, listener, useCapture); // with
```

#### The jQuery Example

*.on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler );*

This one is a bit tricky. The selector and data are optional so there are four valid forms:

```
.on( events                , handler ); // without both
.on( events          , data, handler ); // without selector, with data
.on( events, selector      , handler ); // with selector, without data
.on( events, selector, data, handler ); // with both
```

The problem is that the second and third forms both have three parameters, so it's not obvious how the arguments will be interpreted. It appears that jQuery decides based on the type of the middle argument: if it's a string the third form is chosen; otherwise the second form is chosen.

So the following will have `"hi"` as the selector and nothing as the data argument:

```
.on( events          , "hi", handler ); // "hi" is the selector (!)
```

To force jQuery to use `"hi"` as the data argument, `null` must be given for the selector:

```
.on( events, null    , "hi", handler ); // "hi" is the data argument
```

This is unambiguously the fourth form, and the docs say that a `null` selector is treated the same an omitted selector.

#### A Nested Example

In documentation you'll often see nested square brackets. Here is a simplified example from the documentation for the Unix command `man`:

*man [--warnings[=type]] page*

This means the following forms are valid:

```
man                   javac    # without outer
man --warnings        javac    # with outer (without inner)
man --warnings=number javac    # with outer (with inner)
```

But the following would not be valid:

```
man           =number javac    # is this with or without outer?
```