# Node.js confused syntax for parameters

Tags: javascript, node.js

I was looking at the class Buffer for the method Buffer.alloc() and the documentation has this as the method declaration Buffer.alloc(size[,fill[,encoding]]) and i am confused on what the parameter should be. I come from c++/c/java/c# and the syntax is throwing me off i dont know what size[,fill[,encoding]] is supposed to represent? An array? What is the comma for? Why are these nested? Why is there empty slots? I have looked and cant seem to find an explanation or tutorial? Is this a Node.js specific or is this a JavaScript thing?

Answer (score 4):

The square bracket notation is from [Extended Backus-Naur Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form), and indicates that the enclosed parameters are optional.

`size[,fill[,encoding]]` means that the `size` parameter is required, but `fill` and `encoding` (including the preceding commas) are optional. Also, it means that `encoding` can only be specified if `fill` is specified.

Answer (score 2):

Quoting [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17132014/documentation-for-optional-parameters-in-javascript):

> Square brackets mean the thing inside them is optional – either you have it or you don't. It is a concise way of listing the valid invocation forms.

In your case, the square brackets mean that there are 3 signatures:

```
Buffer.alloc(size                )
Buffer.alloc(size, fill          )
Buffer.alloc(size, fill, encoding)
```

### Hint

*The examples I make deliberately omit parameters for the sake of readability. Whenever you see something like `a(b, , ,)`, imagine there's an `undefined` or `null` in between commas without values, so `a(b, undefined, undefined, undefined)`.*

### Simple Example

Another example could look like this:

```
example(alpha, [, beta], [, gamma], delta)
```

... which means the following signatures will work:

```
example(alpha,     ,      , delta)
example(alpha,     , gamma, delta)
example(alpha, beta,      , delta)
example(alpha, beta, gamma, delta)
```

### Nesting

In your case, `Buffer.alloc(size[,fill[,encoding]])`, the `encoding` parameter must only be provided when the `fill` parameter is provided as well because `encoding` is nested in the square brackets around `fill`. So, the following is invalid:

```
Buffer.alloc(size,    , encoding).
```

### Multiple Nested Params

Multiple parameters can be nested in one level of brackets too:

```
example2(alpha, [, beta, gamma] [,delta])
```

... which means these calls are **valid**:

```
example2(alpha, beta, gamma,      )
example2(alpha,     ,      ,      )
example2(alpha, beta, gamma, delta)
example2(alpha,     ,      , delta)
```

... while these are **invalid**:

```
example2(alpha, beta,      ,      )
example2(alpha,     , gamma,      )
example2(alpha, beta,      , delta)
example2(alpha,     , gamma, delta)
```

### Where to find this notation

As @cybersam said in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40945436/3861083), this notation is called [Extended Backus-Naur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form). It can also be found in a lot of [man pages](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap12.html), the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/) and many other documentations.

Comment: In your simple example, when you have [, beta] what is the purpose of the comma inside the brackets? Does it have a specific meaning or can I ignore?

Comment: It means that you only need the comma when you use the parameter in the brackets.

Answer (score 1):

Arguments in square brackets in documentation typically just mean "this part is optional". In the case of `Buffer.alloc`, it means that you can call it in three ways:

```
Buffer.alloc(size)
Buffer.alloc(size, fill)
Buffer.alloc(size, fill, encoding)
```

The brackets are not actual JavaScript, but are just commonly used to describe this in documentation.